# Predicting from Saved DNN Estimator, Invalid Predict_Dict

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am having a problem with storing and loading a trained model. I am exporting my model as such
`feature_spec = {
        'BUY': parsing_ops.FixedLenFeature(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32, default_value=1), 
        'ASK': parsing_ops.FixedLenFeature(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32, default_value=2), 
        'DIFF': parsing_ops.FixedLenFeature(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32, default_value=3)
    }
    classifier.export_savedmodel('Y:\Checkers\Model1', tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec))`

and this part of the code runs without a hitch, I am just including it in the case that my exporting is skewed. I then try to load this model in on another file as such

```
BUY = float(PriceState.bidVol)
ASK = float(PriceState.askVol)
DIFF = float(PriceState.bidVol) - float(PriceState.askVol)
predict_dict = {
    "inputs": [BUY, ASK, DIFF]
}
predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model('Y:/Checkers/Model1/1529118977')
predictions = predict_fn(predict_dict)
```

However, here I get the error

"
File "./GDAXfinal.py", line 40, in GetPrediction
    predictions = predict_fn(predict_dict)
  File "C:\Users\Andy\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\predictor\predictor.py", line 77, in **call**
    return self._session.run(fetches=self.fetch_tensors, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "C:\Users\Andy\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Andy\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Andy\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Andy\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: 
**Unable to get element as bytes.**
"

I tried setting my inputs to bytes by converting them by first turning the float to strings, and then into bytes ( `bytes(str(<myVal>), encoding="utf-8")` )

and then I get the following error

"

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Could not parse example input, value: '0.0'
         [[Node: ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=3, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], dense_shapes=[[1], [1], [1]], sparse_types=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_example_tensor_0_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/names, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape_1, ParseExample/Reshape_2)]]

"

which I am guessing is because the inputs are floats, but they are being recieved as strings. However, for some reason if i set

```
"inputs": [b'0.', b'0.', b'0.']
```

then the prediction goes through without an error.

But any over slight variation throws the float / str error.

examples:

```
"inputs": [b'0.0', b'0.0', b'0.0']
 "inputs": [b'10.', b'10.', b'10.']
```

throw errors.

I have tried following as many online tutorials with exporting and loading tensorflow premade estimators, but none seem to encounter this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[`build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn) refers to parsing serialized [`tf.train.Example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Example) protocol buffers. To use your SavedModel as-is, you'd need to construct and serialize a `tf.train.Example` and feed it as a single string.

There is also [`tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn) which lets you feed each element of the feature dictionary separately. This should work with your first example (passing something convertible to a floating point Numpy array).